# Split a string in R

Tags: string, r

I have the following string:

```
> position_string
[1] "35.132  46.524  94.997"
```

How do I just get 35.132, 46.524, 94.997 as a list? In python I would do string.split() and that's it but I can't seem to get `strsplit` to work.

Comment: Here it is: strsplit(position_string, " ")

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How about

```
position_string <- "35.132     46.524   94.997"
lapply(unlist(strsplit(position_string," +")),as.numeric)
```

?  The regular expression `" +"` takes care of multiple spaces. (I'm assuming you want to convert the chunks to numeric, but maybe you don't ...)

PS do you really want the output as a list, or actually as a vector?